# gdb, C++, how do I print char** member of a struct

Tags: c++, gdb

as the title says lets say we have

```
struct something{
char** a;
}

.
.
something* nick;
.
```

then on debugging how do I print a[0] ? 
with eg

```
(gdb) p nick->a[0]
```

i get

```
$2 = 0x739b40 "\n\a¶\n"
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: So what's the problem with what you got? What did you expect to see instead?

Comment: @interjay
I want to get the content

Comment: @thahgr if you got the content, then what's the problem?

Comment: Obviously there was some content printed by gdb. Maybe it wasn't the content you expected to see, but you didn't bother mentioning what that is.

Comment: @interjay,
i wrote what i get back, "\n\a¶\n" . 
sorry if i my level is not so good but drop the attitude "didnt bother mentioning..etc"
as Debasish Jana mentions below there is more to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

char ** in this case may mean array of null terminated character buffers. Check if your strings are null terminated or not. Then only

```
(gdb) p nick->a[0]
```

will show some valid null terminated string if any
if you would like to see character by character, you may use this:

(gdb) p nick->a[0][0]

hope that helps
there's no other way